# Set data for a Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Intent:

```
Intent intentEndGame = new Intent(Class2.this, EndGame.class);
```

This code is in the class of Class2. But I want to use the class of Class1. I have tried to change the code to this:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1;
Intent intentEndGame = new Intent(c1, EndGame.class);
```

But it does not work.
Please, can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intentEndGame = new Intent(Class2.this, EndGame.class);
startActivity(intentEndGame);
```

Comment: But I want to for the Class1, with the Class2 it runs. The whole code is in the Class2. But I need start it with the Class1.

Comment: then your class1 should be running for can call to endGame class. In your code, the class2 is running currently

Answer (score 0):

You need call to class1 from class2? for it, you should use the next code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(class2.this,class1.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
/* Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent. */

startActivity(intent);
```

for more information about FLAGS see: for more information about FLAGS see [intent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)